# Android Studio 3.0.1 does not find device

Tags: android, android-studio

After I updted Android Studio to 3.0.1 my device was not found anymore (it worked perfectly before).

What I already tryed:

- switching usb port and cable (should not be the problem anyway since it worked before)
- turn my phone to PTP and back
- checking if google usb drivers are installed in sdk

I dont know how I can get it back to work and I dont know if it might be a bug of Android Studio becuase everything worked before.

My Device - OnePlus 3T

My OS on desktop - Windows 10

I hope somebody can help me here.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart Android Studio after installing Universal ADB Driver?

Comment: Yes I did restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

### install  [Universal ADB Driver](https://adb.clockworkmod.com/)

and configure your device with this tool first and then your device will be found by android studio

Comment: first of all thanks for your anwer. i installed the driver and my phone asked me if i would like to give my computer usb debugging permission. i granted that permission but android studio does still not find my phone.you told i should "configure" my phone and i could not find a way to do that - maybe you can help me here

Comment: did u install you device with this tool ? i think the problem is for windows 10 that’s why your device won’t install by this tool go through this link http://adbdriver.com/documentation/how-to-install-adb-driver-on-windows-8-10-x64.html

Comment: how do i install my phone with this tool? i followed the steps in the guide but nothing changed.